# Building Qt project for C++11 standard

Tags: qt, c++11, build, g++, qt-creator

I am trying to build my Qt project with C++11 standard. I added this flag in the build steps, additional argument option, in the Qt Creator :

```
-std=c++11
```

But I got this error while building :

```
Unknown option -std=c++11
```

g++ version info : `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`

Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable c++11 in qt creator 2.7.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator-2-7-0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the qmake project file, add this line: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`

LE: also 4.6.3 might not support C++11 (as far as i know 4.7 and higher support -std=c++11) so the option for the 0x features implemented might be: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x`

Comment: Agreed.gcc-4.6 does not support -std=c++11 "To enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++0x to your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++0x extensions, add -std=gnu++0x to your g++ command line. GCC 4.7 and later support -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11 as well." http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for the information, i wasn't sure about that.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks.. I updated g++ to 4.7 and used the above stated flag, works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Qt5, add `CONFIG += c++11` to your .pro file, that works on all systems.