# Issue C1083: cannot open include file: 'chrono': no such file or directory pops out

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, c++-chrono

I'm trying to make a program that makes 6 numbers come out randomly.

This is my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Lotto
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    lottogenerator.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    lottogenerator.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

This is my .h file

```
#ifndef LOTTOGENERATOR_H
#define LOTTOGENERATOR_H


#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>

class LottoGenerator
{
public:
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock myclock;

    LottoGenerator();

    std::array<int, 6> get();

private:
    int rand();

    std::mt19937 *engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;

    myclock::time_point beginning = myclock::now();
};

#endif // LOTTOGENERATOR_H
```

This is my .cpp file.

```
#include "lottogenerator.h"

LottoGenerator::LottoGenerator()
    : distribution(1,45)
{
    myclock::duration d = myclock::now() - beginning;
    unsigned int seed = d.count();

    engine.seed(seed);
}

std::array<int, 6> LottoGenerator::get()
{
    std::array<int, 6> numbers;

    numbers[0] = rand();
    numbers[1] = rand();
    numbers[2] = rand();
    numbers[3] = rand();
    numbers[4] = rand();
    numbers[5] = rand();

    return numbers;
}

int LottoGenerator::rand()
{
    return distribution(engine);
}
```

and when I run, "C1083: cannot open include file: 'chrono': no such file or directory" pops out.

It would be grateful if you could help:)

Comment: Which is the compiler you are using? May be does not support C++11 fully...

Comment: I do not use this compiler, but I think you also have to set `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator)

Comment: @CoryKramer Given that the asker uses MSVC, the flag you're referring to is not supported and unnecessary. MSVC supports whatever it supports, there's no way to coax it into supporting more.

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using MSVC 2010. Maybe I'm using too old version like Kuba Ober at below said. I'll install more current version of MSVC and try again. Thanks for the comments guys :)

Comment: I've installed MSVC 2015 community, but still getting same problem. Should I erase MSVC 2010 or is there some setting changes to make at QT creator?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a MSVC version that is too old. The error originates in the compiler, not in Qt Creator.

Comment: I'm currently using MSVC 2010. I'll install more current version of MSVC and try again. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: I've installed MSVC 2015 community, but still getting same problem. Should I erase MSVC 2010 or is there some setting changes to make at QT creator?

Comment: @apolokr2000 Of course you need to set up your Qt version and kit to use the right compiler, and you need to compile Qt with MSVC 2015 (!!).

Comment: Could you tell me how to set up Qt version and kit to use MSVC2015 and compile Qt with MSVC 2015? I have been searching google but can't find the way or maybe I'm not able to understand it T.T. Maybe because I just got into programming. It would be a great help if you could tell me how to set up Qt and compile Qt with MSVC 2015. Can't find anywhere in google.

Comment: @apolokr2000 1. Download and unzip Qt sources. 2. Open up the MSVC command prompt. 3. Make a build folder for Qt (*not* inside of the source folder!). 4. cd into the build folder. 5. `<src path>\configure -opensource -debug-and-release -ltcg -nomake examples -angle -platform win32-msvc2015` 6. `nmake && nmake install` 7. Now you have a built Qt. It will go faster if you download Qt Creator and give `-make-tool jom` to configure; first make sure that `jom.exe`'s folder is added to your path. jom comes with Creator. Note: Qt's documentation has all that!

Comment: Could you tell me how to make a build folder for Qt?  After cd into the build folder, is it right to just copy&paste 5. and 6. into the command prompt? Lastly, could you tell me how I can give -make-tool jom to configure?  I'm an utter beginner at programming and dealing with programs so questions just pop out. It would be very thankful if you could help me with those questions :)

Comment: @apolokr2000 You can create the build folder using any method you know of that creates empty folders. You can copy-paste #5 as long as you prepend it with proper source path for Qt. You give `-make-tool jom` to configure exactly as stated. It's another pair of arguments you pass to it on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous respsonse. So, I've created build folder named 'visual studio qt' and it's path is C:\visual studio qt. My source folder for qt creator is c:\qt. The source folder for qt creator has folders like 5.4, 5.5, docs, examples, vcredist etc..
I 'cd'ed into c:\visual studio qt at VS 2015 MSBuild command prompt and I copy&pasted <C:\qt>\configure -opensource -debug-and-release -ltcg -nomake examples -angle -platform win32-msvc2015.
Then the message saying 'acces denied' comes up. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: @apolokr2000 The angle brackets `<` and `>` were just to indicate which part you need to replace. You weren't meant to keep them. Finally, you want sources for Qt, not Qt Creator. Qt Creator is a nice IDE, but it has nothing to do with what you're trying to do. Qt is a toolkit. Qt Creator is an IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response.  Somehow dll files in my computer are missing. I think maybe it was too hard to solve at my current level of knowledge about computer. Just have to skip this part and work on other things first and then come back.  Anyway, it was really great to receive comments from you. Thanks Kuba Ober~^^