# QVector of arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qvector

I'm trying to hold polynomial coefficients in `QVector`. My polynomials are of degree 2, so it has three numbers.

When I define `QVector<double[3]> zeros_Real(n + 1)` I get an error (below). First, I thought I could use `QVector<QVector<double>>` but it will be speed and memory problem, so I decided to not do that.

Why can't I have a `QVector` of `double[3]` elements?

The error:

```
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
21:27:01: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled11 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QVector` (like `std::vector`) requires its elements to be copyable (it has to copy the elements during reallocation). Arrays can *not* be copied, that implies you can't have `QVector<double[3]>`.

The working alternative is to use `std::array` (C++11 or later):

```
QVector<std::array<double, 3>>
```

Which *can* be copied. Qt doesn't have its own `QArray`, so you have to mix the standard library and Qt containers like this.

Comment: your answer is awesome, but i cant call array or std::array , which i defined using namespace std and include array library already.

Comment: What's the error? Are you compiling it as C++11 or later?

Comment: there isnt any error, just i cant call ,i mean not coming from CTRL+Space . i'm using Qt Creater 3.5.1 and Qt version 5.5.1 which i dont know which C++ version compiler is ?

Comment: I don't know what that shortcut does in Qt Creator, if your program doesn't start in an IDE, the most common reason is that it didn't compile. You should be able to see something.

Comment: now when i compile it ,i get this error 

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\c++0x_warning.h:32: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^

Comment: That's what I was thinking. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator).