# Can not use C++11 in Qt

Tags: qt, c++11

Since Qt 5.7, C++11 support is mandatory. For some reason one large old project does not accept the C++11 arguments. It doesn't matter if I use "CONFIG += c++11" or any other; C++11 only features do not work and therefor I can not compile the project.

> C:\QtE\5.7\android_armv7\include\QtCore\qbasicatomic.h:61: error:
>   error "Qt requires C++11 support"
>       ^

The compiler arguments do contain "-std=c++11 -std=c++0x" if I use "CONFIG += c++11" in the .pro file. The target platform is Android ArmV7. SDK R24 and NDK R10E are used.

C:\SDKs\Android\android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-builtin-memmove -std=c++11 -fPIC -ansi -fpermissive -finline-functions -Wno-long-long -g -g -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O2 -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DQZXING_LIBRARY -DZXING_ICONV_CONST -DDISABLE_LIBRARY_FEATURES -DNOFMAXL -DBOTAN_DLL=Q_DECL_EXPORT -DBOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_GETTIMEOFDAY -DBOTAN_HAS_ALLOC_MMAP -DBOTAN_HAS_ENTROPY_SRC_DEV_RANDOM -DBOTAN_HAS_ENTROPY_SRC_EGD -DBOTAN_HAS_ENTROPY_SRC_FTW -DBOTAN_HAS_ENTROPY_SRC_UNIX -DBOTAN_HAS_MUTEX_PTHREAD -DBOTAN_HAS_PIPE_UNIXFD_IO -DBOTAN_TARGET_OS_IS_LINUX -DBOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_CLOCK_GETTIME -DBOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_DLOPEN -DBOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_GMTIME_R -DBOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_POSIX_MLOCK -DBOTAN_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_ENGINE -DBOTAN_HAS_DYNAMIC_LOADER -DBOTAN_BUILD_COMPILER_IS_GCC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICKWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_WEBSOCKETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_POSITIONING_LIB -DQT_ANDROIDEXTRAS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB

Any idea is welcome :)

Comment: Have you tried capitalizing the 'C' in C++? All of the documentation I've read has it as such, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Qt isn't a compiler, and it's the C++ compiler which decides whether it's compiling C++98 or C++11.

Comment: It is strange, usually it works. Don't you use an old compiler/SDK?

Comment: If you have `-std=c++11` in the compiler command line, the qmake part should be working correctly. Maybe the compiler is too old to know C++11? Which one is it?

Comment: I'm using SDK R24 and NDK R10E. Also tried R11C but according to Digia "There are significant issues with the gcc version in r11, making it unusable for building Qt unfortunately."

Comment: NDK10E apparently includes the GCC 4.8 compiler which definitely supports C++11.

Comment: Updated main post to show compilation arguments

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Oktalist: updated main post

Comment: I suspect the problem is the `-ansi` option. This is equivalent to `-std=c++98`, according to the GCC manual.

Comment: @Oktalist: You are right, one of my submodules had this argument used. I removed it and the project began to build with C++11 :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator)s accepted answer, It says `CONFIG += c++11` requires Qt 5. Are you sure you are using Qt 5?

Also, It also says if you use gcc/clang you should use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` (or `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x`).

since you are building an android project, it will use gcc. Change `CONFIG += c++11` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` and tell me what happened.

Comment: Sure I'm using Qt5. Same error with "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11" and "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x". All results in "C:\QtE\5.7\android_armv7\include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:61:4: error: #error "Qt requires C++11 support""

Comment: Then What version do you have exactly?

Comment: Would you try adding `QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -std=c++11`?

Comment: or changing `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` to `gcc:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late answer. Tried em' all, same result "Qt requires C++11 support"

Comment: @metaDom Okay. Tell me when you found the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the .pri sub-projects used the argument "-ansi" which is equivalent to "-std=c++98". This prevents the compilation with C++11.

Thanks to Oktalist for the solution comment :)