# QDesktopServices::openUrl() not working Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpushbutton, qdesktopservices

This is my code:

```
QPixmap map(":/Medal.jpg");
QIcon ico(map);
ico.addPixmap(map);
QPushButton *p = new QPushButton;
p->setIcon(ico);
QString link = "http://www.google.com";
QObject::connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()),window,SLOT(QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl (link))));
```

The pic is showing up but it is not opening the browser. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Opps sorry. A noob's mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a lambda function:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton p("Click me");
    QString link = "http://www.google.com";
    QObject::connect(&p, &QPushButton::clicked, [&link](){
        QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));
    });
    p.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

or with `std::bind()`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QUrl>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton p("Click me");
    QString link = "http://www.google.com";
    QObject::connect(&p, &QPushButton::clicked, std::bind(QDesktopServices::openUrl, QUrl(link)));
    p.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**note:**

you need to enable C++11 in Qt, for this review the following question: [How to enable C++11 in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator), which indicates that you add `CONFIG += c++11` in your .pro

Comment: The first one is showing:F:\Projects\Calci\main.cpp:94: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     });

Comment: The second one: F:\Projects\Calci\main.cpp:94: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     });
     ^

Comment: Last problem: As you know i have added an image so now it is showing F:\Projects\Calci\main.cpp:125: error: no matching function for call to 'QVBoxLayout::addWidget(QPushButton&)'
     lay->addWidget(p);

Comment: It is not showing properly so here is the link: http://www.mediafire.com/file/rz8l5qfr25j4i5q/main.cpp

Comment: The best answer.

Comment: @Coder7 
Do not use pointers unnecessarily, it is bad programming practice, also read about http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html and https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax